# Get URL part only android

Tags: java, android

I have the URL

**`http://www.facebook.com/post/ll.html`**

I want to spilt the url into `http://www.facebook.com/post/` and `ll.html`

Please help

Comment: Use Java's String.split().

Answer (score 4):

One way of doing this is:

```
String myStr = "http://www.facebook.com/post/ll.html";
String strEnd = myStr.substring(myStr.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

strEnd will have the string you desire.

Answer (score 1):

```
String x = "http://www.facebook.com/post/ll.html";
String[] splits = x.split("/");

String last = splits[splits.length - 1];
String first = x.substring(0, x.length() - last.length());

System.out.println(last); // 11.html
System.out.println(first); // http://www.facebook.com/post/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (null != str && str.length() > 0 )
    {
    int endIndex = str.lastIndexOf("/");
    if (endIndex != -1)  
    {
        String firststringurl = str.substring(0, endIndex); 
        String secondstringurl = str.substring(endIndex);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to approach this is to also use [the URL class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html), as there are a lot of gotchas if you just do simple string parsing. For your example:

```
// Get ll.html
String filePart = url.getPath().substring(url.getPath().lastIndexOf('/')+1);

// Get /post/
String pathPart = url.getPath().substring(0, url.getPath().lastIndexOf('/')+1);

// Cut off full URL at end of first /post/
pathPart = url.toString().substring(0, url.toString().indexOf(pathPart)+pathPart.length());
```

This will even cope with URLs like `http://www.facebook.com:80/ll.html/ll.html#foo/bar?wibble=1/ll.html`.